# In R, how to control spacing within mathematical annotations in plots

Tags: r, plotmath

I'm trying to insert mathematical expressions into the titles of plots. I need to control the spacing within the mathematical expressions. For example, I'd like to show the expression "64/8 / 8" except with division signs instead of slashes. I need narrow spacing around the first division sign and broad spacing around the second. How can I do this?

Reproducible code:

```
# just produces uniform spacing:
plot( runif(10), runif(10) )
title( expression( 64 %/% 8 %/% 8 ) )

# returns an error
plot( runif(10), runif(10) )
title( expression( 64 %/% 8 ~ " " ~ %/% ~ " " 8 ) )
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just do `title( expression( (64 %/% 8) %/%  8 ) )` or `title( expression( over((64 %/% 8) , 8 ) ))`. Seems like that would be more clear.

Comment: Yes - the mathematical expressions are actually stimuli from an experiment designed specifically to investigate how variation in spacing affects how people interpret the expressions. I need to match the physical properties of the actual stimuli as exactly as possible - not just transmit an equivalent meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second @MrFlick's comment above, but here is one way using `phantom`:

```
title(expression(paste(64 %/% 8, phantom(0) %/% phantom(0), 8)))
```

Comment: You don't really need `paste` there. `title( expression( 64 %/% 8 *phantom(0) %/% phantom(0) *8 ) )` would do just fine.

Comment: meh, to each his own.

Comment: What are the asterisks doing there @MrFlick?

Comment: An expression must be a valid language expression. The `*` is basically a silent multiplication to put a term into an expression.